# Silverlight and SOAP WebService

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, web-services, soap

Good day to you,

I have a big problem deploying a Silverlight application. Ive got a WebService that is uploaded in the root directory on the server. I have added a service reference in my Silverlight project. When I uploaded my Silverlight app to the web I came to a crossdomain problem. I fixed it by copying crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml to the root folder of my web server. And now I'm getting a HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer exception with Arguments : Not Found. The WebService id running on the server and I can access it when I navigate to www.mydomain.com/MyService.asmx . In the silverlight config , everzthing is specified correctly. In my Web.config there is nothing about the webservice. Please help me, I need to complete this project and I dont know where to find answer for this problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Install Fiddler2

http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp

watch this

http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/help/video/default.asp

An i think you will find an answer very soon....

Comment: Fiddler is showing me : ; Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.